# Unable to use automatic PR service

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I've been trying to use **bitbake PR service**. I've followed the instructions in https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/PR_Service and added these lines to my `local.conf` file:

```
PRSERV_HOST = "localhost:0"
INHERIT += "buildhistory"
BUILDHISTORY_COMMIT = "1"
```

I expected that PR values of my recipies will be incrementing automatically after each change, but they are still the same

Comment: Are you using `PR = ` in the respective `.bb` files? Is bitbake-prserv running on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Setting PRSERV_HOST is all you need, and it works for me.  It turns PR=r1 into r1.1, r1.2, r1.3 on each build.  If that isn't working, what version of oe-core are you using?

Comment: I'm using fido branch of yocto

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the versioning server being enabled you also need to make sure your .bb's are using the auto rev:

```
PV = "1.0.0.0+git${SRCPV}"
```

and they pulling from some source

```
SRC_URI = "git:/my_repo/program.git"
```